# Apache SetEnv with special characters

Tags: php, apache, url, setenv

I'm trying to set an environment variable in Apache using SetEnv in my vhosts.conf file with the following:

```
SetEnv FACEBOOK_SECRET 13jf93jjdshut7qpm321b1vv5nod973j10
SetEnv DATABASE_URL "postgresql://postgres:sdfesf@localhost:5432/public"
```

The FACEBOOK_SECRET environment is showing up in php with the genenv() function, but the DATABASE_URL is empty. I'm assuming it's due to the special characters in the connection string, but I don't know if or how to escape those characters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put the value to set in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` as it appears apache doesn't like the localhost keyword in the virtualhost configuration block.

```
SetEnv DATABASE_URL "postgresql://postgres:sdfesf@127.0.0.1:5432/public"
```